# Windows form: Black filled combo and input boxes when run from other machine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I extract a 2003 solution and converted it into 2005 since im using that ide.  All works fine and I successfully edit and run it.  Ive noticed that in the GUI **form1** uses (developer made DLL)controls with input boxes and comboboxes on it (*something like a control consisting subcontrols*). In contrast with my newly added windows.form.comboBox, that is, built-in control from windows and plain single control.

When Im all done and finished, i passed my project in .zip to another machine and other person tried to run it there. The application was working fine but **all input boxes and combo boxes turns black filled** except the newly added windows.form.combobox.

I dont know if the other machine uses vs2003 or 2005.

**Update**

I guess the custom made DLL doesnt work properly in VS 2005 environment.

I made a new project and compile it in vs 2003. (No more conversion to vs2005)

it works Perfectly fine on the other machine.

For the answer given by Ankit: I also suspect that it might be that the Default color for the custom controls was not set properly. But its not the case since i explicitly change the default color of the custom control and still nothing happens.

"It might be that customized DLL compiled from a Lower version wont successfully work with the newer version." - my opinion.

Still i doubt my opinion. Could anybody give me a better insight? Although im not probleming on this issue now, this is still my issue and I want an answer for it.

Comment: don't post an answer with follow-up info. This isn't a forum and the way to do that here is to edit your question. Check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: still bug is still present, this thread was years ago, but do you remember if you fixed it by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom input boxes might be using some different value for Backcolor property instead of default windows control background color. Default control color varies from computer to computer based on the windows theme.

Comment: But Still, I'd wonder in comboboxes, remember that it has a down arrow on its right, that arrow are also been black filled. Is it normal?